# How to keep VSTO solutionId same as previous version

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

We had a Word template-level addin which was built in .NET 4.0 but due to some requirement changes, we were forced to downgrade the solution to .NET 3.5. We had to recreate the entire project in a new solution. Now the client already has a lot of documents integrated with the old vsto/dotx which does not fire up the new customization we've deployed. It is because the _AssemblyLocation (custom document property, which gets injected to the dotx during publishing) still refers to the old solutionId instead of the new one. If I modify the new manifest to have the old solutionID, this gives a signature mismatch error.

Please also note that, this solutionID has the same syntax as the GUID mentioned in AssemblyInfo.cs but they are not the same. I assume this gets generated when a vsto solution is published.

Any idea how can I make the new version work with previous documents? I know this might not be clear for everyone to understand so please let me know if anything is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the fix, it was actually very simple. I just needed to open the csproj file and update the solutionId GUID to the old one. Not sure why the solution wise text search did not find this, probably VS does not read the content of the csproj file itself for search.